# Should changing the order of template parameters in the "template<...>" line for a specialization result in a duplicate definition, or ambiguity?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a question related to [Edge-case: When (only) reversing order of template parameters in specialization, can non-specialized version ever be reached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071415/edge-case-when-only-reversing-order-of-template-parameters-in-specialization#11071670).

This is a theoretical question involving code that would probably considered to be poorly written.  However, I want to thoroughly understand template syntax.

Suppose two template specializations differ *only* in the order of template parameters within the `template<...>` line, as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

// Primary template
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
class A
{};

// Specialization #1
template<typename T2, typename T3>
class A<int, T2, T3>
{};

// Specialization #2
// Differs only in order of parameters in the "template<...>" line
template<typename T3, typename T2>
class A<int, T2, T3>
{};

int main()
{
    A<int, int, int> a; // <-- Compiler error: Ambiguous template specializations
    return 0;
}
```

In the Visual Studio 2010 compiler, the error involves the ambiguous template specialization: `'A<T1,T2,T3>' : more than one partial specialization matches the template argument list.  could be 'A<int,T2,T3>' or 'A<int,T2,T3>'`.

In particular, the error is *not* `'A<int,T2,T3>' : class template has already been defined`, which is the error produced when the second specialization is character-for-character identical to the first (i.e., the order of template parameters is not reversed, and reads `template<typename T2, typename T3>`, just as in specialization #1).

I think, however, that the order of parameters listed in the `template<...>` line within a template specialization makes **no difference**.  Specifically, I think that the purpose of the `template<...>` line in a specialization is *only* to identify the tokens that appear in the specialized type name (`A<int, T2, T3>`) as syntactically valid template parameters, and not typos.  According to this reasoning, the order of parameters in the `template<...>` line for a template specialization should make **no** difference, and two template specializations that differ character-for-character **only** in the order of these parameters should be considered duplicate definitions, rather than ambiguous specializations.

If I am correct, than the Visual Studio 2010 compiler is correct in that it reports an error in this case, but incorrect in that it identifies the error as an ambiguous specialization, rather than as a multiply defined specialization.

Am I correct?  Does the order of template parameters in the `template<...>` line of a template specialization make *no* difference, such that two template specializations which are identical otherwise character-for-character should be considered redundant definitions of the same template specialization, rather than two different, but ambiguous, template specializations?

If I am incorrect, than it must be that indeed the two specializations in the code above are *different* (i.e., not multiply defined).  If so, can someone please explain why they are different and how this difference might be demonstrated by client code?

Answer (score 1):

The identity of a partial specialization is its argument list passed to its template. Template type parameter names denote specific dependent types, whose identity includes their position in their template parameter list and the nesting depth of their template parameter list (i.e. a member template's list is one more level nested than its enclosing template if the member template is a member of a class template).

This makes sense because you need to mangle two function templates different that overload each other and differ only in their template parameter order. Their instantiation behavior is different because their position directly correspond to the respective argument in a function template calls' template argument list.

If you reorder their the positions, the argument lists become different because different types are passed as arguments. So you are not redefining partial specializations.

Comment: By 'template parameter list', I assume you mean the line `template<...>` within the specialization definition.  If so, then my understanding is that the types denoted by the parameter names are determined not by the `template<...>` line, but rather by the class name line (`A<...>` in my example code).  If I'm right, then reordering parameters in the class name line (i.e., `A<...>`) should result in different argument lists and hence different specializations; but reordering them in the `template<...>` line should leave the specialization unchanged.

Comment: The nondependent type in a specific instantiation  (after substitution) is determined by the order of appearance in the argument list. But the preinstantiation (dependent) types are not affected by this.

Comment: This seems to agree with my assessment that two specializations are redundant (rather than ambiguous) if the only difference is the order of parameters in the `template<...>` line.  I would like to confirm this; and if it's wrong, then I'd like to see a counterexample where the behavior is different for the ambiguous specializations (assuming each were present by itself) when used by some example client code.

Comment: @dan qhat testcase are you looking for? you apready seem to have such a testcase. if you have the same order for both, it becomes a multiple def error. and for different order but unchanged argument lists, it becomes ambiguous later.

Comment: I claim that the case reported as *ambiguous* is actually not ambiguous, but *redundant*.  This is testable.  If it is ambiguous, then testing each (by itself) should result in different behavior in *some* circumstance.  If this isn't possible - if they *always* result in *identical* behavior in *every* circumstance, then they are, by definition, identical.  (This assumes the code is the same for each, of course.)  I cannot construct any case where the behavior would be different.  This is the test case I'm looking for.  If it's not possible, then I think I'm right to claim they're duplicates.

Comment: They behave identical in any case, yet they are not defining the same template. The Standard defines when two partial specializations define the same partial specialization independent of their behavior.

Comment: It would certainly be helpful if the compiler identified two partial specializations that aways match the same types. However I think that's impossible to solve in the general case.

Comment: I think determining that two partial specializations are identical (based only on signature) during the initial template parsing stage (when the template declarations are first seen), rather than simply reporting ambiguity at time of instantiation, is trivial: if the signatures are identical except for the order of parameter names in the `template<...>` line, then the template specializations are duplicates, not ambiguous.  (Ignoring the choice of parameter names, of course.)

Comment: @Dan That looks trivial to me too, but that's not the only case. What about `template<int I> struct Foo<I, bool_<I + I>>; template<int I> struct Foo<I, bool_<I * 2>>;`. Or `template<typename T> struct Foo<T, bool_<(sizeof(T) >= 1)>>; template<typename T> struct Foo<T, bool_<(sizeof(T) > 0)>>;` (for function templates only, if we have such overloads that "look different" but when instantiated always produce the same values, the spec renders them "ill-formed; no diagnostic required"). I don't know why your checks aren't required, but they won't catch all cases of "redundant" specializations.

Comment: In the examples you give, the function signature is different.  I am specifically referring to cases where the function signature is identical in every respect - except that the order of parameters in the `template<...>` line is different.  Can you think of such a case that is non-trivial, and where two specializations are distinct (i.e., ambiguous), rather than being duplicates?  (Of course, by 'in every respect' I don't include the names of the parameters or arguments.)

Comment: @DanNissenbaum i thought we were at partial specializations of class templates instead of about function template overloads. If you talk about function templates, then that's entirely different, because they directly correspond to explicitly passed template arguments. For primary class template declarations, that is true too. As said, if you restrict the diagnosis to identical argument lists modulo the order of appearance of template parameters, I think that's trivial for the compiler to do.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum if you want to ask the committee why such partial specializations aren't rejected as ill-formed, I recommend to post at https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/std-discussion . I suspect however that this may be too much of a corner case to warrant adding a rule to the spec. Compilers are always free to warn about some nonsensical code.

Comment: As long as I understand that the order of parameters in the `template<...>` list is irrelevant, and assuming that the parameters (simple, or complex w/expressions) appearing within the list associated with the class name remains identical (`A<...>` in my example) that the template specialization is equivalent - i.e. that the order of parameters in the `template<...>` line has precisely 0 impact whatsoever on anything, then I am satisfied that I understand this basic detail about templates.

Comment: I was just surprised that the compiler issued an "ambiguous" error, rather than "already defined" error, which led me to think that I was not understanding templates properly.  Instead, it seems that either the specification is misleading in this area, or that the VS compiler issues a misleading  error message.

Comment: Also, for clarity: in my comment (5 above), I did not mean to say "function signature" - I meant to refer to the entire template specialization signature: the `template<...>` line, the line with the class name and its template parameters (`A<...>` in my example), and the function signature.  In that case, if the full expression inside the `A<...>` is identical for two specializations, so is the function signature, and the only difference in the parameters in the `template<...>` line is their order, than the two specializations are identical, and a 'multiply defined' error should be emitted.

Comment: Finally, I don't see this as a corner case, because it applies to every template specialization with more than 1 parameter in the `template<...>` line.  For *any* such specialization, the order of parameters can be rearranged and the template specialization remains unchanged.  Therefore, I think a rearrangement of the order should leave the template specialization unchanged.  This has an effect which is easily demonstrated by simply swapping the order in a template class function definition: currently, an error is issued.  In my opinion, this should be legal syntax.